# how to make a recursive function to analyse this file

Tags: string-manipulation, recursion, parsing

I am stuck at this problem beginning

We assume we have keyword k, and the structure in the file:

file.txt

```
struct test12{
 struct myBlock1{
  struct theColor1{
  }
  struct notText{
    struct Light{
    }
    struct super{
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Can someone point me in how to make a recursive function who has as input the file.txt and outputs the whole nested tree of nested element ?
Obs: the file can have an infinite nr of levels in theory (we assume around 100 max)

Comment: Somthing like `kName1[chrs, kName2[chrs, kName3[]]]`?

Comment: there is at least one space or new line or tab between k and name

Comment: There are no `<random characters>` in `k name3`. So are the `<random characters>` parts actually optional?

Comment: I will remove the random characters to make it easier to implem

Comment: It would increase your chance for an answer if you gave a very precise description of the file format and some actual example data with no `...` in it. For example, do you require handling "comments" (the `//` things)?  Parsing is not trivial in Mathematica.  If the file format is sufficiently complex, I'd use external parsing tools such as Boost Spirit, through LibraryLink.

Comment: Could you give a precise example of the output you want and of course corresponding to your example ? Note that the output tree will have the same number of levels that the input.

Comment: The output would be a tree structure:
ex name1 would be the rot and has as child name 2 who has two childs name 3 and 4 . etc

Answer (score 5):

Let me give you at least a start, because in general, I like this question. There are some things that are still unclear. For instance, you write in the comment

> and has as child name 2 who has two childs name 3 and 4 . etc

Regarding the example you gave, this is not correct. `name2` has *one* child which is `name3` which in return has one child `name4`. Look at how you placed the braces. If you want to make `name2` have 2 children it should look like

```
k name2{
    k name3{
      }//end name 3
    k name4{
      }//end name 4
}//end name 2
```

Furthermore, if the structure of you file is really consistent, then you could probably use a much simpler approach the using a recursive parsing function. Let's assume you have a [`file.txt`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QQexfVm4) which contains (I left out all the comments)

```
k name1{
 k name2{
  k name3{
  }
  k name4{
    k name5{
    }
    k name6{
    }
  }
 }
}
```

then you can write a routing that does what you probably want. Let us define two string patterns that match the beginning of a struct and the end respectively:

```
$start = WhitespaceCharacter...~~"k"~~" "~~name__~~"{"~~WhitespaceCharacter... :> name;
$end = WhitespaceCharacter...~~"}"~~WhitespaceCharacter...;
```

If you now try to parse one element, you need to extract the name (as in `name3`), you need to parse possible other elements that are inside and you need to parse the closing brace. And, an element always starts when the line matches `$start`

```
parseElement[] /; lineMatches[First[$start]] := 
  With[{head = ToExpression[StringReplace[nextLine[], $start]]},
   head[parseArgs[], parseEnd[]]
   ];
parseElement[___] := ParseErrorAt[parseElement, nextLine[]];
```

The implementation of the functions `lineMatches` and `nextLine` is simple and I will show it at the end. OK, you see that every `parseElement` creates a new `nameX[...]` construct. Since we already have the closing bracket for this, `parseEnd` just needs to check whether we have indeed a closing `}` and then it should simply vanish. This is realized with `Sequence[]`. Note that we throw away the current `}` line with `nextLine` so that we can go on with the parsing process:

```
parseEnd[] /; lineMatches[$end] := (nextLine[]; 
   Unevaluated[Sequence[]]);
parseEnd[___] := ParseErrorAt[parseEnd, nextLine[]];
```

Parsing the arguments is simple. If you meet the start of a new element, we parse the element and then go on parsing possible other new elements that could follow. If we don't meet the start of a new construct, and in fact meet the closing of an already opened struct, we simply do nothing:

```
parseArgs[] /; lineMatches[First[$start]] := 
  With[{e = parseElement[], r = parseArgs[]},
       Unevaluated[Sequence[e, r]]
       ];
parseArgs[] /; lineMatches[$end] := Sequence[];
parseArgs[___] := ParseErrorAt[parseArgs, nextLine[]];
```

What is left is the helper functions, that provide us with the next line and make it possible to check patterns on the next line before throwing it away:

```
Module[{data = {}},
 open[file_] := data = Import[file, {"Text", "Lines"}];
 lineMatches[pattern_] := 
  StringMatchQ[First[data], pattern] /; data =!= {};
 lineMatches[___] := False;

 nextLine[] := Module[{result},
   If[data === {},
    result = EndOfBuffer,
    result = First[data];
    data = Rest[data];
    ];
   result
   ];
 ]
```

Now, everything should be set up to test it:

```
open["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QQexfVm4"];
parseElement[]

(* name1[name2[name3[], name4[name5[], name6[]]]] *)
```

Comment: just a comment "k" can be any string like "animal", "plant" etc but i think we can consider k="k" for the moment

Comment: @timoftebogdan Since you always used the same `k`, I thought this is constant, but it is no problem to add it to the pattern and include it in the final tree.

Comment: yes i think so...-_- ''

Comment: is this solution recursive ? I cant figure it lol :D

Comment: I updated the input text with a concrete example :). I tried your solution and it doesn't work on the concrete example :(